# Error is thrown while trying to upload cookbook to hosted chef server

Tags: chef-infra

I want to upload a cookbook to hosted server.

**Command Run**
knife cookbook upload CookbookName

**Error Received**
"ERROR: Error connecting to https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/opscode-platform-production-data/organization"

Comment: Are you on some kind of restricted network?

Comment: Nope, its not. I am able see the client list in my workstation.

Comment: Seeing the client list isn't relevant, are you able to access public AWS services?

Comment: As i said, i need to maintain my cookbooks in hosted chef server and i don't understand the need for AWS services. and I am new to this chef, please guide me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Hosted Chef uses AWS S3 for storing cookbook data, so you need to be able to access the hostname shown in that URL.

Comment: Thanks for the information and when i tried to access that hostname, i received an error "SignatureDoesNotMatch"

Comment: How about this URL? https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/i.coderanger.net/thisisfine.png

Comment: (make sure you are testing from the _same machine_ as your running knife from)

Comment: I am able to access this URL "s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/i.coderanger.net/thisisfine.png"  and i'm sure that i'm testing from the machine where i'm running knife.

Comment: Then that error makes no sense.

Comment: One more thing i need to mention here is, when i execute "knife ssl check" i got an error message followed by this :
Connecting to host api.chef.io:443
Successfully verified certificates from `api.chef.io'

Answer (score 0):

Did you create file knife.rb in ~/.chef/ directory? (https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_knife.html)

Comment: yes i did and it looks like : current_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)

log_level                :info
log_location             STDOUT
node_name                "XYZ"
client_key               "E:/chef/chef-repo/.chef/XYZ.pem"

chef_server_url          "https://api.chef.io/organizations/X"
cookbook_path            ["E:/chef/chef-repo/cookbooks"]

validation_client_name   'ABC'
validation_key           'E:/chef/chef-repo/.chef/ABC.pem'
cache_type               'BasicFile'